# Android Publication Steps

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play

I have some doubts in steps of preparing the application to be published.
I have reached step on [Preparing for Release](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html#publishing-build) guide. So I only need to do these remaining steps?

1. I use Eclipse, export the Application using Export Wizard. But then, in Building with Eclipse section:

   > The Export Wizard compiles your application for release, signs your
   >   application with your private key, and optimizes your application with
   >   the zipalign tool.

   Do I need to zipalign again?
2. Obfuscate the application.

Feel free to edit my post if I miss something. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to run zipalign again. ADT will do that for you when you export a signed application package.

You don't need to obfuscate your code yourself, so long as you have [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) configured properly. When you export a signed application package (which builds your application in release mode), ProGuard will obfuscate your code for you.

Enabling proguard is as simple as adding `proguard.config=proguard.cfg` to your project.properties file if you have the automatically generated proguard.cfg in your project root.

You really just need to follow the [signing instructions](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#align). They are pretty straightforward and will guide you through all the necessary steps.

Comment: So as long as I have enabled proguard, don't need to worry anything else?

Comment: Yes, that is all you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

No need for zipalign tool.
When you'll use the The Export Android Application wizard to create the apk - just follow the steps and it will create a private key for you in case you don't have one.
These are *[the exact steps](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#ExportWizard)* (done it!):

> To create a signed and aligned APK in Eclipse:
>
> 1. Select the project in the Package Explorer and select File > Export.
> 2. Open the Android folder, select Export Android Application, and click
>      Next. The Export Android Application wizard now starts, which will
>      guide you through the process of signing your application, including
>      steps for selecting the private key with which to sign the APK (or
>      creating a new keystore and private key).
> 3. Complete the Export Wizard
>      and your application will be compiled, signed, aligned, and ready for
>      distribution.