# Android keytool certificate

Tags: android, import, key, apk, keytool

I have a certificate in RFC 1421 format. I imported it to keystore using keytool.

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keypass android -storepass android 
-alias my_key -file my_crt.crt -keystore my_project.jsk
```

When I try to export my apk in Idea I got this error:

> **Error:** trusted certificate entries are not password-protected

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: You can check out my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321796/android-publication-steps/11321955#11321955

Comment: i try to update old version of app and i have only this sertificate

Comment: in this case it's a dup of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459719/android-i-lost-my-android-key-store-what-should-i-do

Comment: but i have sertificate text in RFC format in-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
.........................................
-----END CERTIFICATE----- format

Comment: You can do it manually like you're doing now or like described here: http://www.androiddevelopment.org/tag/keytool/ but I prefer to let eclipse handle this for me (using the procedure described on the link I posted on my first comment)

Comment: @alfasin The question is not asking how to generate a new keystore and certificate. The question is how to import an existing certificate file into an existing keystore in a way that will work when signing APKs.